# Simple jQuery click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hover

I have this page I'm creating and I can't seem to get a simple jQuery click to work at all. Tried hover, tried click, tried mouseover, etc. No luck. jQuery 1.7.1 is installed. Not sure why the functionality is not working. Anyone have any thoughts. Link and javascript to follow. Thanks in advance.

http://www.bigideaadv.com/adaptive/

```
    $("#menu_show").click(function () {
        alert('Works!');
    });
```

Dave